# How to manipulate CSV data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, row

I am trying to make a bank program in which you for now you have the option to change your password in choice '2'.I tried doing it but of no avail.Can anyone tell me how do I change the password which is stored in row 2 in 'store.txt'.
Example:
This is my data stored in file 'store.txt'

```
hello,me,0
bye,you,0
```

What I want to do is the change password of username 'hello' to say 'yolo'.How do I do that?
This is my code:

```
import csv
run=True
while run==True:
    print "1)Create a new account"
    print "2) Change Password"
    choice=input("Enter your choice over here: ")
    #This part takes the input from the user and then stores it in 'store.txt'
    if choice==1:
        a=input("Enter how many people to register: ")
        for i in range(0,a) :
            #Stores username and password
            a=raw_input("Enter username: ")
            b=raw_input("Enter password: ")
            c=0
            #If username already exists, stop the process.
            with open ('store.txt','r') as store:
                reader = csv.reader(store)
                for row in reader:
                    if a==row[0]:
                        print "User already exists in our database , please try again."
                        break
            store.close()
            #If username is not there , write it down to store.txt
            with open ('store.txt','a') as store:
                storeWriter=csv.writer(store)
                storeWriter.writerow([a,b,c])
            store.close()

    if choice==2:
        print "Change password"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace a value in a file:

```
with open('store.txt','r') as f:
    reader = list(csv.reader(f))
    for row in reader:
        row[1] = "some-new-value"

with open('store.txt','w') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    for row in reader:
        wr.writerow(row)
```

There are also many ways that your code should be improved:

- It's better Python style to include spaces around operators like "==" and "=" (a great resource: [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces))
- You don't need to `close()` your file if you are using a `with` block.  `with` closes your file automatically.
- You should include some condition that will break your `while` loop; otherwise it will loop indefinitely.
- Your conditional `if` statement is wrong.  You want something like this pseudocode: `if username exists: print "some message" else: open file and append line`

Comment: When i use your code , i get an error saying  
>AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'writerow'
I tried changing it to just 'write' and it worked but then my file i clear , that is no data is there.

Comment: Sorry about that - fixed the typo.  The code in my answer will definitely work for you.  Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: My pleasure!  Good luck -